# Resize UIImageView in UITableViewCell upon rotation

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I'm setting a `UIImageView` into my table cells during `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableVw cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

They are stretchable images (created with stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth)

How can I update their `size` when my table view is rotated to another orientation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create an IBOutlet for each object to be resized.  Open interface builder and connect the outlets to your file's owner.

You will need to override the method
willAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration
This is for making changes that will happen before the roation animation is finished, or you could use 
willAnimateSecondHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration
if you want the new positioning to occur at the same time the rotation finishes.

Inside the animate method, you will redraw the frame depending on which orientation the phone is now in:  Example:

button1.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 125, 125);

Comment: So, maybe i should create a UIImageView iboutlet that resized automatically, but instead of setting the image in IB, I use the setImage method and it might all go well. I'll try.

Comment: I actually ended up using the autoresizingMask property, but this got me on the right path.  Thanks.